# How to correctly call a git submodule symlinked?

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, subprocess, sublimetext3

On the Sublime Text [Package Control](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues) issue:

1. [Why ignore VCS-based packages accordingly to this message?](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/1233#issuecomment-308921923)

I find out what causes this error. I had the package `All Autocomplete` triggering it. Then I gone to the folder `Packages/All Autocomplete` and noticed it is a git repo synlinked. Then I deleted the `.git` file which points to `gitdir: ../.git/modules/All Autocomplete` and recloned the repository, so its files are within the repo. Then the package control stopped throwing the error for the package `All Autocomplete` and started doing the same error for the next package which also a git submodule and had the `.git` synlinking to the parent git folder.

It is because the `All Autocomplete` is a submodule, therefore its gits files are in:

1. `gitdir: ../.git/modules/All Autocomplete`

Now you can reproduce it, but you need:

1. To make your Packages folder a git repository, and add the `All Autocomplete` as a submodule.
2. Delete it, and install clone your `Package`  folder repo with `git clone --recursive`

This will create the `All Autocomplete` as a git submodule and store its files on the parent git folder at:

1. `gitdir: ../.git/modules/All Autocomplete`

I am calling this subprocess on a git submodule symliked:

I did some testing using the python interpreter, and it is a problem with the `proc = subprocess.Popen()`:

```
>>> import os
>>> import subprocess
>>> startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO();startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen( ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe', 'symbolic-ref', '-q', 'HEAD'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, startupinfo=startupinfo, cwd='D:/SublimeText/Data/Packages/amxmodx', env=os.environ )
>>> proc.communicate()
(b'', None)
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen( ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe', 'symbolic-ref', '-q', 'HEAD'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, startupinfo=startupinfo, cwd='D:/SublimeText/Data/Packages/All Autocomplete', env=os.environ )
>>> proc.communicate()
(b'refs/heads/master\n', None)
>>>
```

On the first command, I do with the package `amxmodx` which has the `.git` file symlinking to `gitdir: ../.git/modules/amxmodx`. And we got the output `(b'', None)`.

On the second command, I do with the package `All Autocomplete` which has the `.git` folder inside it, because I just cloned it on as a git submodule. Therefore as its installation was not by `git clone --recursive`, the `.git` is 
a folder, and is not a symlinked to `gitdir: ../.git/modules/`, it has the actual git files contents on it.

Hence we got the output `(b'refs/heads/master\n', None)`, which works correctly and make the package control not throw the error.

How to make the call to a symlinked git submodule with `subprocess.Popen()` to work properly as a call to a git submodule not symlinked to `gitdir: ../.git/modules/` which produces the output `(b'refs/heads/master\n', None)` instead of `(b'', None)` for a symlinked submodule?

---

My system info/versions are:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.13.0.windows.1

$ systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Version"
OS Version:                10.0.15063 N/A Build 15063

$ python --version
Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (32-bit)
```

---

## Update

I also tried using `os.system`:

```
>>> cur_dir = os.getcwd()
>>> os.chdir(r'D:/SublimeText/Data/Packages/All Autocomplete')
>>> os.getcwd()
'D:\\SublimeText\\Data\\Packages\\All Autocomplete'
>>> os.system( r'"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe" symbolic-ref -q HEAD' )
refs/heads/master
0
>>> os.chdir(r'D:/SublimeText/Data/Packages/amxmodx')
>>> os.system( r'"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe" symbolic-ref -q HEAD' )
1
>>>
```

I also opened a issue for this on the git for windows:

1. [How to correctly call a git submodule symlinked?](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1209)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the problem. When I do git `clone --recursive` the submodules are not checkout on their default branches, therefore the command `git.exe symbolic-ref -q HEAD` returns always empty.

The solution is just go to each submodule and do git checkout master or the main default branch, therefore the command will work properly and return the desired values:

```
>>> cur_dir = os.getcwd()
>>> os.chdir(r'D:/SublimeText/Data/Packages/All Autocomplete')
>>> os.getcwd()
'D:\\SublimeText\\Data\\Packages\\All Autocomplete'
>>> os.system( r'"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe" symbolic-ref -q HEAD' )
refs/heads/master
0
>>> os.chdir(r'D:/SublimeText/Data/Packages/amxmodx')
>>> os.system( r'"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe" symbolic-ref -q HEAD' )
refs/heads/master
0
>>>
```