# How to clone a git repository with its submodules checkout on their default branches?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules

On the question:

1. [How to correctly call a git submodule symlinked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591825/how-to-correctly-call-a-git-submodule-symlinked)

Was figured it out it is necessary to checkout the git submodules to their default branch when a `git clone --recursive` is performed, but how to do that?

I tried searching and found this other question:

1. [Easy way pull latest of all submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules)

Suggesting to use the command `git clone --recurse-submodules` but after cloning the repository its submodule still not checkout on their default branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git submodule foreach` to run an arbitrary command in each submodule. The `--recursive` flag will recurse through the submodules' submodules. `git remote show [name-of-remote]` will say which branch `[name-of-remote]` currently has active. Combining them with a few other tools to clean up `git remote show`'s output gives:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive "git checkout $(git remote show origin | grep 'HEAD branch' | sed 's/.*: //')"
```

This is, of course, dependent on already having cloned the submodules.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can do the command `git clone --recursive https...; git submodule foreach ...`, then it should clone everything and checkout their master.

Comment: Is there a solution platform independent or a Windows version of it? If I run this command on Windows, it would not have available the `grep 'HEAD branch' | sed 's/.*: //'` part.

Comment: @user I believe `grep` and `sed` are included in the standard Git for Windows installation, though depending on which options you selected during installation, you may need to use git bash rather than cmd.

Answer (score 2):

`git submodule foreach git checkout master`

Comment: Thanks, It sure helps but what happens with those submodules which its default branch is not master?

Answer (score 1):

1. First clone repo with submodules first:

`git clone --recursive --branch develop https://github.com/aem-design/aemdesign-parent.git`

2. Then force all submodules to the default branch:

`git submodule foreach -q --recursive 'branch="$( git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD --short | grep -oE "[^/]+$")"; git checkout $branch'`